# Making a dataframe of parent IDs

Tags: python, beginner, pandas

I am quite new to scripting, and here is my first code I wrote. The goal of the code is to extract a parent ID based on a child ID. I would appreciate some constructive criticism and aggressive checkup. The codes works and does what it's supposed to do. But how can I make it more pythonic? more passionate?

```
import codecs

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def import_file(path):
    '''imports the .csv files as a pandas dataframe
    Args:
        path (csv file): Takes in the path for the .csv file

    Returns:
        Returns a pandas dataframe
        '''
    with codecs.open(path, "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fdata:
        df = pd.read_csv(fdata)
    return df


def appends_address_before_name(file):
    '''Appends the address before the name ID name
    Returns:
        Returns the file, with address appened to column name.
        '''
    file['ID'] = [address + str(col) for col in file['ID']]
    return file


def create_parent_name(file, column_name: str):
    '''This will create a parent name based on the ID column

    Args:
        file: takes in the dataFrame created from appends_address_before_name function

        column_name: Takes in the column name where the parent name
        will be extracted from.The logic is to split it on the last dot.
        [[parentname].[+ childname]]

    Returns:
        Returns a pandas dataframe with a new column called parentID
        '''
    file['parentID'] = [
        x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] if '.' in x else x[:-1] for x in file[column_name]
    ]

    return file


address = 'New_Jersey_'
file_1 = import_file(r'C:\humans.csv')
file_2= appends_address_before_name(file=file_1)
file_3= create_parent_name(file=file_2 , column_name = 'ID')

print(file_3)
```

The input CSV is a column of values separated with decimal places like the following:

```
ID

99.99.9
100.42.3
```

Example output

```
parentID

New_Jersey_99.99
New_Jersey_100.42
```

Furthermore, I feel like the way I am passing variables between the functions at the end of the code seems quite basic and terrible. What can I improve in the above code and how can I improve it ?

A screenshot of the code working

[image]

Comment: @200_success I edited the question. On the other hand, I want to improve the logic of the code and how variables are passed between functions. The code works as expected. I was wondering if this looks like something ready for production.

Comment: Can you post a sample from your csv, including header?

Comment: What is the reason behind dropping the last character if there is no `'.'` in the ID? It seems to result in weird things like `'NewJersey_"`.

Comment: @Graipher you are right, the parentID for this one will be just `NewJersey`, I added an extra underscore in the `address `, thats wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should decide if your functions modify the object they receive or if the return a modified object. Doing both is just asking for disaster. After your code has finished, `file_1`, `file_2` and `file_3` are all identical.

The usual convention is to return `None` (implicitly or explicitly) if you mutate any of the inputs. In the rest of this answer I have decided to mutate the inputs.

Besides that, `pandas` is most effective if you use its vectorized functions. For columns with strings, it has a whole lot of methods which are vectorized. You can access them with `df.col_name.str`. You can find some examples in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html).

Your `appends_address_before_name` function could be simplified a lot because string addition is vectorized:

```
def appends_address_before_name(file):
    file["parentID"] = address + file["parentID"]
    file["ID"] = address + file["ID"]
```

And your `create_parent_name` function could be:

```
def create_parent_name(file, column_name: str):
    file["parentID"] = file[column_name].str.split(".").str[:-1].str.join(".")
```

With a csv file like this:

```
ID
99.99.9
100.42.3
101
```

This produces

```
df = import_file(file_name)
create_parent_name(df, 'ID')
appends_address_before_name(df)
print(df)
#                     ID           parentID
# 0   New_Jersey_99.99.9   New_Jersey_99.99
# 1  New_Jersey_100.42.3  New_Jersey_100.42
# 2       New_Jersey_101        New_Jersey_
```

Note that the order of the calls has changed, so that ids without a `.` are handled correctly.

---

As for general structure:

- Seeing docstrings is very nice (I omitted them here for brevity)
- Python has an official style-guide, PEP8. It recommends writing `x = some_thing(a=3)`, so surround equal signs with spaces when assigning but not when setting keyword arguments.
- You should wrap the main calling code in a [`if __name__ == "__main__"` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

Comment: can you kindly elaborate more on  `object they receive or if the return a modified object. `, where in my code am I returning or modifiying objective ?

Comment: so you removed the variables, i.e. `file_2` as in  `file_2= appends_address_before_name(file=file_1)`
, as you modified the original file rather than returning it?

Comment: @Matthew: When you do `file["ID"] = ...` you modify the `file` object in place. Afterwards your return `file`, which is still the same object, but modified.

Comment: the concept of returning a file or modifying in place was unknown to me, thanks. What more ? is the docstrings okay ? is the overall structure okay ?

Comment: @Matthew: I figured out how to get exactly your behaviour and added some comments on general structure.